# How to round by an "interval"

Tags: r, rounding

Let `VetA = c(3.12,3.13,3.23,3.29,3.46)`
and I wish to round it by `0.05` interval. A solution could be:

```
round(vetA/5,digits = 2)*5)
```

Which will give me `c(3.1, 3.15, 3.25, 3.3, 3.45)`.

However, what if my desire changes, and now I would like to round them by 0.25. What should I do? 
Also, this thinking could grow much more, as I could as well wish to round by `15` interval numbers like `12,15.2,20,55,24`.

For that reason, could you help me thinking in a *generic* function? I'm having troubles modeling just the grouping by `0.25`, imagine making a more generic one.

Comment: you're on the right path, and i encourage you to keep thinking about how to make such a function; as pointed out, you can check the source of `round_any` to confirm your solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `plyr` solution is to use `round_any`

```
library(plyr)
VetA = c(3.12,3.13,3.23,3.29,3.46)
round_any(VetA,0.25,f = round)
```

Comment: Also, looking at the source code with `plyr:::round_any.numeric`, it turns out the calculation for this is very close to what was in the OP.